# Adding custom attributes to a PropagatedSpan in WebFlux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, reactive, open-telemetry, spring-micrometer

I have a SpringBoot application with:

#### Setup

- SpringBoot 3.0.8 WebFlux
- Micrometer + OTL
- Context propagation enabled
- Libs:

  - `io.micrometer.context-propagation`
  - `io.micrometer.micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel`
  - `io.opentelemetry.opentelemetry-api:1.23.1`
  - `io.projectreactor.reactor-core-micrometer:1.1.1`
  - `io.opentelemetry.instrumentation.opentelemetry-instrumentataion-annotaions:1.32.0`

Trying to add a custom attribute to a Span. When the `traceparent` header is passed as `00-<trace_id>-<span_id>-01`, `Span.current()` returns a `propagatedSpan`. Any attributes added to this gets lost and is not propagated to AppInsights. But if the `traceparent` is not passed, `Span.current()` returns a `SdkSpan` and any attributes added gets propagated to AppInsights.

As this is for a orchestration service, it is vital that the trace parent is preserved to provide e2e visibility in AppInsights. Additionally, there are no custom webfilters were added and no manual instrumentation is done.

Just want to understand how to add an attribute to the `propagetedSpan` or how to properly configure the app to preserve traces as well as the added attributes.